# How can I Build SEF Url for Joomla Site

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I Develop One Component for Joomla Site using Core PHP. I Pass Following query for route.php in Component.

```
JRoute::_('index.php?com_examples&view=profiles&layout=item_addtome&id='.$itemval["p_id"]);
```

When I Print $query in Route File. It's Display

```
Array ( [Itemid] => 114 [option] => com_example )
```

Only. View and Layout Not Passed. How to do Retrieve this Item.  or Give Some simple Example of Create SEF URL for Component Reference Matirial

Comment: Try: `JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_examples&view=profiles&layout=item_addtome&id='.$itemval["p_id"]);` I see all other components using option=com_examples in not only com_examples.

Comment: where is your route.php code?

Answer (score 0):

If you an excellent example on how to build a router file, check the `router.php` file under the `components/com_newsfeeds/` folder. This router has a concise `build` and `parse` methods.

Also, as Paules in the comment said, you are missing the `option` in your URL, so your URL should be:

`JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_examples&view=profiles&layout=item_addtome&id='‌​.$itemval["p_id"]);`

It's really weird that you're able to printout those values in the router.php file despite the fact that you're not passing the `option` GET parameter properly.